# Create visual studio solution template - multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-templates

I'm stuck on this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308) for creating a multi-project visual studio template. I'm specifically stuck on this line:

`Select the files and folders to include in your template, right-click the selection, click Send To, and then click Compressed (zipped) Folder. The files and folders are compressed into a .zip file.`

I did the following steps:

1. Create 2 projects. (MyProj.Web and MyProj.Service)
2. Reference MyProj.Service in MyProj.Web.
3. Export both. They are now in a `.zip` file.

What do I do from here?

My intentions are: Make solution folders where some dlls will be (DI, unit testing frameworks, etc). Have these dlls referenced. Reference projects in other projects. Rename part of the projects. For eg. the ability to replace `{MyProj}.Service` with `NewName.Service`

Comment: @Adron: did you ever get around to writing about this?

Answer (score 2):

The other parts includes making the .vstemplate xml file and placing the zip in the ProjectTemplates.

Per the article:

> Put the .zip template file in the Visual Studio project template
>   directory. By default, this directory is \My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\

The Visual Studio template will then be available from `File` > `New Project`. If making a template for a single item, place it in the \ItemTemplates folder instead to make it available from the `Add New Item` context menu in Solution Explorer.